# Build Option<Vec<String>> from Iterator<Item = String>

Tags: rust

I have the following logic implemented:

```
let assigned_courses: Option<Vec<String>> =
    schools.courses.iter().map(|c| c.to_string()).collect();
```

Since this is an optional variable, I get the error:

```
value of type `std::option::Option<Vec<std::string::String>>` cannot
be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::string::String>`
```

How do I handle this issue? If it is not optional, it does not throw this error.

Comment: Wrap it in `Some`? `let assigned_courses: Option<Vec<String>> = Some(schools.courses.iter().map(|c| c.to_string()).collect())`;

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: Your code is trying to convert an iterator of strings to `Option<Vec<String>>`, and the question title says the opposite. Do you understand what an `Option` is and why are you building one? When would you want your vector to be `Some`, and when would you want it to be `None`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```rust
let assigned_courses: Vec<String> =
    schools.courses.iter().map(ToString::to_string).collect();
```

Or if you really need an `Option` for later usage within your context

```rust
let assigned_courses: Option<Vec<String>> =
    Some(schools.courses.iter().map(ToString::to_string).collect());
```